# Firefox and Chrome appending underscore before and after file name while Internet Explorer is working fine

Tags: java, spring

Firefox and Chrome are appending underscores before and after the file name while Internet Explorer is working fine.

Firefox and Chrome give: `_Warrant_Amendment_5485_14_March_2014.pdf.pdf_`

IE gives: `Warrant_Amendment_5485_14_March_2014.pdf.pdf`

Below is the code

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\" + fileName + ".pdf\");
```

Comment: You have written both with underscores. And you need to provide more information if you want help. Is this in s JSP?

Comment: You seem to be appending `.pdf` to the filename when it isn't needed.

Comment: I agree but why is it getting appended by underscore (_) in Firefox and chrome. whereas in IE, its working fine with the name downloadPdfFrominvDmsViewLibraryLink.pdf

Comment: Are the backslashes escaping the double quotes that follow them? Try: `"inline;filename=" + fileName;` maybe?

Comment: response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\\" + fileName + ".pdf\\");           i have added the above code still facing the same issue. Kindly reply.

Comment: Check if there is space at the beginning of the filename. I think this is because of the space at the beginning of the filename. If there is a space at the beginning then browser tries to append an underscore with the filename. I faced similar kind of issue while exporting to pdf from data table.

Answer (score 14):

I resolved a similar issue by removing the quotes from the filename value (which in my case were not required).

I note that [rfc6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) says a quoted-string for the filename value should be acceptable.  At this point I have not investigated further.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same problem and solved it thanks to user650881's reply.

The problem was I had this:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + filename + "\"");
```

And worked when I changed it to this:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

Note the \"" after filename=

Hope it helps

Comment: Weird, I fixed this issue with the complete opposite. I changed response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{ FileHelper.GetValidFileName(fileName) }\""); to response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename={ FileHelper.GetValidFileName(fileName) }");

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue and I thought that **user650881**'s answer is the solution, but in my case problem was I was parsing the file name from `Content-Disposition` wrongly, that is I kept the last quote `"` char from `attachment; filename="filename.ext"` string in the filename (`filename.ext"`) which was automatically transformed to `_` when downloading the file like this:

```
  const link = document.createElement('a');

  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  // Contains 'filename.ext"' string which is replaced by 'filename.ext_`
  link.download = fileName; 
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are characters that are invalid for a file name.
C#'s [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?view=net-6.0) lists most.

Round, curly and square brackets may be legal in a file name (it is on Windows), but files with them will also get the underscores added by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + request.Filename + "\";");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any correct answer so here's what fixed it for me.
I found this issue weird, then it made sense once I found out.

In my case when I was splitting the filename from Content-Disposition headder > filename, I was also including the quotes in the string. I had to split after the opening quote and before the closing quote.

The downloaded filename then changed from:

> _YYYY-MM-DD_historical_price_template.csv _

to

> YYYY-MM-DD_historical_price_template.csv

And here's my code before:

```
const fileName = res.headers.get("content-disposition").split("filename=")[1].split(";")[0]
```

after:

```
const fileName = res.headers.get("content-disposition").split('filename="')[1].split('";')[0];
```