# ResponseEntity results in additional underscore ( _ ) in filename's extension

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a GET mapping like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadDocumentById/{symName}/{docId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> downloadStuff(@PathVariable String symName, @PathVariable String docId)
        throws IOException {
    File newFile = null;
    String fullPath = documentService.getDocumentById(symName, docId).getName();
    newFile = new File(fullPath);
    System.out.println("newFile_Name:" + newFile.getName());
    HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    respHeaders.setContentLength(newFile.length());
    respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment; filename=" + newFile.getName(), null);
    return new ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>(new FileSystemResource(newFile), respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The sysout shows the newFile_Name as sample1.pdf but not sure why my return statement is downloading the filename as sample1.pdf_

What am I doing wrong here? Or how can I fix it?

Comment: You can make a file object with any path, you haven't checked if the file exists. The file path is created by `String fullPath = documentService.getDocumentById(symName, docId).getName();` . So what happens in there?

Comment: If you please notice `new File - newFile` is created using `documentService.getDocumentById(symName, docId).getName()` name. And that is what sysout is producing (correctly)

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477273/firefox-and-chrome-appending-underscore-before-and-after-file-name-while-interne). Not sure, but maybe it'll fix your problem